# DNS server in country A and hosting in B

Tags: dns, web-hosting

This is something where I get confused..

Say I acquired a domain name blabla.ge (ge is for Georgia) and hosting my files with US based hosting company. What are the downsides if any and is there an option to change the DNS server?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, there is no real downside. The tld is really not that important to basic usage. Yes root servers factor in here but really nothing that will impact your daily activities and you don't really need to worry.

For the nameservers, you can change these to any servers you wish and have access to manage the records. Location isn't important other than basic routing and response time. Nameservers generally should be on diverse networks and diverse locations per Best Practices. I have nameservers available in multiple countries and there's nothing wrong with that. If you are using the nameservers provided by your registrar, you likely have the diversity I mentioned, although they may be located in a single country (which is fine).

I have multiple domains registered with tlds such as .nl, .im, .com.de, etc. Some of these point to US-only nameservers, some use nameservers in multiple countries and a couple use the nameservers provided by my registrar (who I purchased the domain from).

From there, my A records point to servers in diverse locations.. Primarily the US and Netherlands. This set up works great, performance is adequate and there are no major downsides to doing it this way. You can change your nameservers for the .ge domain to use US servers or you can leave them overseas and use A records to point to your server(s) in the US. You can debate which method would be "best" given a situation but neither method is "wrong."

So in short, no major downside to doing this at all. And yes, changing your DNS server (nameserver) is always an option. Hope this helps.